# Alpine JS animation x-transition behaviour isnt working

Tags: html, tailwind-css, alpine.js

I followed some tutorial about AlpineJS by Andreas Jud on Youtube. I came to the part to animate dropdown menu button. I've tried to put the leaving animation. Here is the code :

```
 <div x-show="dropdownOpen" x-cloak class="absolute right-0 bg-white text-black shadow rounded-lg w-40 p-2 z-20"
                    x-transition:enter="duration-1000 ease-out"
                    x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 -translate-y-5 scale-90"
                    x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 translate-y-0 scale-100"
                    x-transition:leave="duration-1000 ease-out"
                    x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100 translate-y-0 scale-100"
                    x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0 -translate-y-5 scale-50"
                >
```

So far, what I know is that scale supposed to change the size right ? For resizing element, and translate is for kind of like moving. But when I changed it to this following value I get some different behaviour:

1. scale-70 : the scaling doesnt happened, only the translation does
2. scale-50 : the translation doesnt happened only the scaling does

So it almost like a new animation. What happened here ? Did I do something wrong here ? Thanks y'all

Full code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/output.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://img.icons8.com/stickers/100/fire-element.png" type="image/png">
    <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
    <title>Tutorial</title>
    <style type="text/tailwindcss">
       

       h1 {
        font-family: 'Lobster';
       }
    </style>
<body class="bg-gray-200">
    <header class="bg-gray-800 h-20 text-white flex items-center justify-between px-8 sticky top-0 z-50">
        <logo>
            <a href="/" class="flex items-center gap-1">
                <img class="h-8 -mt-1" src="https://img.icons8.com/stickers/100/fire-element.png" alt="fire-element"/>
                <span>Awesome</span> 
            </a>
        </logo>
        <nav>
            <ul class="flex items-center navitems">
                <li><a href="/" >Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Create Post</a></li>
                <li x-data="{ dropdownOpen: false }" class="relative">
                    <a x-on:click="dropdownOpen = !dropdownOpen" x-on:click.away="dropdownOpen=false" class="cursor-pointer select-none">
                        <img class="h-8 rounded-full object-cover bg-teal-200" src="https://img.icons8.com/stickers/96/bart-simpson.png" alt="bart-simpson"/>
                        <img class="w-4" src="https://img.icons8.com/plasticine/64/expand-arrow.png" alt="expand-arrow"/>
                    Bart
                    </a>
                    <!-- Dropdown menu -->
                    <div x-show="dropdownOpen" x-cloak class="absolute right-0 bg-white text-black shadow rounded-lg w-40 p-2 z-20"
                        x-transition:enter="duration-1000 ease-out"
                        x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 -translate-y-5 scale-90"
                        x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 translate-y-0 scale-100"
                        x-transition:leave="duration-1000 ease-out"
                        x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100 translate-y-0 scale-100"
                        x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0 -translate-y-5 scale-90"
                    >
                        <ul class="hoverlist [&>li>a]:justify-end">
                            <li><a href="">My Profile</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Log Out</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my input.css:

```
:root {
  --primary: rgb(88, 40, 244);
  --primary-hover: rgb(69, 29, 200);
  --font1: "Lobster", sans-serif;
}

@layer components {
  .bg-primary {
    background-color: var(--primary);
  }

  .bg-primary-hover:hover {
    background-color: var(--primary-hover);
  }

  .hoverlist > * {
    @apply hover:bg-gray-100 rounded-md transition duration-150;
  }

  .hoverlist > * > a {
    @apply p-2 flex block items-center;
  }

  .highlight {
    @apply !bg-indigo-100;
  }

  [x-cloak] {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  font-family: var(--font1);
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
}

.font1 {
  font-family: var(--font1);
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 15px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  background-color: white;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.navitems > li > a {
  @apply h-12 px-4 hover:bg-gray-700 rounded-2xl flex items-center gap-4;
}

.headerhero {
  @apply text-7xl leading-tight font-bold mb-4;
}

.buttonhero {
  @apply bg-primary hover:bg-primary inline-flex flex-wrap items-center justify-center flex-shrink-0 text-center rounded-md cursor-pointer px-4 min-h-10 font-semibold shadow-md transition-transform duration-200 active:scale-95 text-white bg-primary hover:bg-primary;
}
```